# Django.po with Korean Symbols

Tags: django, internationalization

I have a question regarding Django i18n and the django.po file.

I am new to i18n so please excuse my noobness.

I am using the Google Tranlator Toolkit to upload a text
file of English words and phrases.

In this case I am converting to Korean.

Here is a sample of four words:

Gender
Date of Birth
Country
City / Town

Here is the output on-screen:

성별
생일
국가
도시

When I click save it saves to a text file.

My questions is is it OK to use the Korean symbols
direct into my django.po file?

Everything is working OK in my application so far.

Looking at the django/contrib/auth/local/ko/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
file I can see it's using a format like:

msgid "Password"
msgstr "ë¹„ë°€ë²ˆí˜¸"

So far it seems to work OK saving the symbols I have
but I'm just wondering if this is the corect way to do this.

So far I'm intending to use google to translate my English
into various languages and then I'll save them each
to their respective django.po file.

Any tips or advise much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

I'm doing the same for my translation into portuguese, but I'm also, not quite sure, if it's the best way to achieve this.

Be careful if you aren't doing the translation manually but using this command

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
```

every time you update the file, check if everything is correct, because it can do associations, for instance I've writen:

first template:

```
pt = 'maça e cenoura'
```

second template:

```
pt = 'maça e cereja'
```

doing the automatic translation, it will assume both are equal strings, which they aren't.
I'm not able to explain why, because I don't know why this happen.

A solution could be to use a string 'X' and translate to both languages the text.

```
msgid = 'X'
pt = 'maça e cenoura'
en = 'apple and carrot' #different files (just as example, I put them together)
```

But like I told you, I'm also just starting using this feature

Comment: Hi, I am doing my translations like this: django-admin.py makemessages -l de --extension=html,js,txt As I am translating HTML, javascript (for form validation) and txt for email confirmations. The 'X' you suggest is interesting I've not seen that before.

Comment: for now I'm just translating html but I've come across the `fuzzy` problem (where it assume the string 'maça e cenoura' and 'maça e cereja' are equal) so my best option was to use just an id and translate in both languages. Not sure if it's the best option, but assuming strings are equal is also a problem, be careful with that

Answer (score 0):

python manage.py makemessages -l ko   output django.po default is ansi format,

you must convert it to utf-8  to allow non-ansi chars in it.